# avconv change volume of an audio file

Tags: audio, volume, avconv

I would like to change the volume of the second audio file but so far everything I tried is not working.

`avconv -i input1.mp3 -i input2.mp3 -aq 1 -filter_complex amix=inputs=2:duration=first:dropout_transition=2 output.mp3`

Answer (score 1):

This is using FFmpeg, but I suspect it would be similar for avconv.
All I did was adapt [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/769195/515930) until it seemed to have the desired effect on my test files.

Test files

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "anoisesrc=d=20:c=brown:r=44100:a=0.5" -q:a 1 input1.mp3
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "sine=frequency=1000:duration=20" -q:a 1 input2.mp3
```

No attenuation

```
ffmpeg -i input1.mp3 -i input2.mp3 -filter_complex \
"[0:a]volume=1.0:precision=fixed[a0]; \
 [1:a]volume=1.0:precision=fixed[a1]; \
 [a0][a1]amix=inputs=2:dropout_transition=2" -q:a 1 output1.mp3
```

50% attenuation of the first input file

```
ffmpeg -i input1.mp3 -i input2.mp3 -filter_complex \
"[0:a]volume=1.0:precision=fixed[a0]; \
 [1:a]volume=0.5:precision=fixed[a1]; \
 [a0][a1]amix=inputs=2:dropout_transition=2" -q:a 1 output2.mp3
```

50% attenuation of the second input file

```
ffmpeg -i input1.mp3 -i input2.mp3 -filter_complex \
"[0:a]volume=0.5:precision=fixed[a0]; \
 [1:a]volume=1.0:precision=fixed[a1]; \
 [a0][a1]amix=inputs=2:dropout_transition=2" -q:a 1 output3.mp3
```